# Do they make a tv wall mount that will come out and down?

Tags: product-recommendation

I want to mount my tv above the fireplace. I would like a mount that will let me pull it out and then down so it will clear the mantle and not make us have to look up too far when watching it. If they make something like this, what would it be called?

Comment: I need the same! The only thing i found is like a swivel arm- that will swing the tv completely out of the way(but you need the same amount of space to the left or right).. nothing that goes up/down..  or ask this guy  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKwdWgXXnK0

Comment: I know this isn't a good answer, but if you need this, then doesn't it mean this is not the right spot to mount the TV? If you're a casual TV watcher that uses it very little, then it shouldn't be a big deal to have it above the mantel. If you watch it quite a bit, isn't it more likely that it's going to be left "down" position most/all the time anyway, blocking your fireplace? Why not just find somewhere else to mount it and/or rearrange your furniture layout so you can permanently mount it without issue?

Comment: I have one other wall I can put it on due to wall shape and entry ways. To be honest I do not like the way the furniture can be laid out with it on that wall.

Comment: also, most of the time we can watch it just fine with it up. The uncommon case is when we have enough company over to use all of the furniture. Some people will be straining to look up quite a bit.

Comment: I'm looking for the same and just found a possibility on Amazon by searching for "mounts that go out and down". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Mounting http://www.dynamicmounting.com/ has a product specifically for this purpose. Be forewarned, they are not cheap (well, maybe cheap compared to a motorized lift, but not cheap compared to simpler articulating arms).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a motorized TV lift like this [one](http://www.activateddecor.com/lifts/index.html). I have had clients have this. They are not cheap...

Comment: These seem to only go vertically and not horizontally.